# How to get a URL for a JSON file?

Tags: android, django, android-studio, django-rest-framework, retrofit

I am an android developer. I am designing an application in which I need to use some JSON files created using django as database.

However, since I am not a django developer and my friend is, all the JSON filesa are in his machine. I know I can simply transfer the files to mine, but my machine does not have the tools for django framework design.

I am using retrofit to access data from the JSON file. However, the retrofit needs a URL(the source of the JSON file). Is there any way to get this combination working with django on his computer and Android studio on mine?

Comment: I would usually just make a GET request from my phone app to my webapp.

Answer (score 0):

You need to host your files in a Server

for testing purposes you can use free hosting for example : [freeHosting](https://www.000webhost.com/)

you upload your json files in that server and you use your domainName / yourFileName as a link

for example :

```
https://yourDomainName.000webhostapp.com/yourJsonFileName
```

after you're done with testing consider using using a paid hosting as free ones are not reliable